# Element.getAttributeNames vs. Element.attributes

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm wondering what the advantages and disadvantages are(if any) to using Element.getAttributeNames to access the attributes of an Element DOM object instead of using Element.attributes.

MDN's Element.getAttributeNames mentions that it is a more performant alternative to Element.attributes but doesn't mention any downsides(browser compatibility, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

[`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) is more widely supported; it was implemented in Chrome 26 (early-2013) and is supported on IE11. In contrast, [`getAttributeNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames) is much more recent: Chrome 61 (mid 2017) with no IE support. (implementation among other browsers is on a similar timeframe.)

Another difference is that `getAttributeNames` returns an array, which can be convenient because you can use array methods on it, for example

```
elm.getAttributeNames().forEach((name) => {
  // do something
});
```

as opposed to

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  elm.attributes,
  (name) => {
   // do something
  }
);
```

(or spread the `.attributes`: `[...elm.attributes]`, though that requires creating an extra intermediate array)

Also note that `.attributes` returns an array-like object that contains *both* the node names and the node values, whereas the `getAttributeNames` array contains only the node names.

To use `getAttributeNames` in older browsers, make sure to include a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames#Polyfill).